# Axes3D.view_init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'roll'

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to change the elevation, azim and roll of my matplotlib 3d projection which should be straightforward following the standard view_init:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/view_angles.html

However I am getting an error when trying to use roll:

`Axes3D.view_init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'roll'`

Is this functionality still available?

Please see me code below:

````
fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        for ll in range(dataset[0][:,:,0:64].shape[2]):       
            xlist = [x for x in range(1, (len(dataset[0][frame,:, ll])+1))]
            plt.plot(
                xs=np.clip(dataset[150,32,:,ll], 0,1),ys=xlist,  zs=ll, label='Raw ' + str(1))
            plt.title(("All A-scans of frame: " + str(frame)))
        ax.set_axis_off()
        ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=45, roll=15)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()```
````

Comment: What version of Python and matplotlib are you using?